# How I can set my elasticsearh port to 9300?

Tags: groovy, grails-plugin, elasticsearch-plugin

I am trying to set my elasticsearh port to 9300 but when I set http.port to 9300 elasticsearch not work. 
Actually I'm develop a grails web-app using an elasticsearch instance but when i run the app the following error appear

```
ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'searchableClassMappingConfigurator': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available: []
Message: Error creating bean with name 'searchableClassMappingConfigurator': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available: []
```

I have read other answer but no one have resolve my problem. Any ideas??

My config file is:

`elasticSearch {
    client.mode = 'transport'
    client.hosts = [
            [host:'localhost', port:9300]
    ]
    disableAutoIndex = 'true'
}`

Now, grails show me the following error:

```
[localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing the application: No datastore implementation specified Message: No datastore implementation specified
 Line | Method
 ->>  135 | doCall                    in    ElasticsearchGrailsPlugin$_closure1
 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
 |    754 | invokeBeanDefiningClosure in grails.spring.BeanBuilder
 |    584 | beans . . . . . . . . . . in     ''
 |    527 | invokeMethod              in     ''
 |    262 | run . . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
 |   1145 | runWorker                 in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
 |    615 | run . . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
 ^    745 | run                       in java.lang.Thread
Error |
Forked Grails VM exited with error
```

Really I surfed in web but i didnt find a solution to this problem, I need connect to an ES instance. Thanks in advanced. Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my Cofig.groovy file I add next code:

```
elasticSearch {
client.mode = 'transport'
client.hosts = [
        [host:'localhost', port:9300]
]
disableAutoIndex = 'true'
}
```

And change the disableAutoIndex to true in the DefaultElasticSearch.groovy file and work. Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch server opens 2 ports by default: [9200](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-http.html) for communication with clients, and [9300](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-transport.html) to communicate between nodes. You have to change one of them.

Comment: I change the port in my Config.groovy where the elasticsearch config it is, but the error remaind. I have an elasticsearch instance, with a node, however i cant realized what is wrong. Any idea??

Comment: Could you attach your config and describe your setup?

Comment: This is my config file